# Vector Resultant Angle and Direction

Tags: c++

I am working with set of points, and my goal is to add 4 vectors together and calculate the resultant between start and end point,

Since I already prepared the code to do the above part which seems to be working fine but am not to sure about it.

Anyway the real reason I am posting this question is to do with the resultant direction and angle.

I find it hard to either understand the concept of finding resultant angle and direction as well as PROGRAMMING wise.

Consider this scenario....Image

[image]

1st add vectors "Head 2 Tail"

From what I have learned about vector addition is to subtract  x2 - x1, y2 -y1 this will dive me the misplacement difference and do the same calculation for all the points from A-E

To get the resultant I  square root  all the points x to power of 2 and add all the  y position to power of 2.

This ideology seem to work fine.....

But the QUESTION here is how do i get the angle and direction of that resultant....?

the code I use to calculate resultant:

```
 double Pta; 
    double Ptb;
    Point  vect;
    float R1, R2;
    float resultant;

    for(vector<Point>::iterator iter_a = Left_Arm_xy.begin()+1; iter_a != Left_Arm_xy.end(); ++iter_a)
    {

        if(center.y <= 240)
        {
            vect.x = iter_a->x - (iter_a -1)->x;
            vect.y = iter_a->y - (iter_a -1)->y;

            vect_add.push_back(Point(vect.x,vect.y));


                for(vector<Point>::iterator iter_v = vect_add.begin(); iter_v - vect_add.begin() + 4 < vect_add.size(); iter_v+=4)
                {

                        R1 = iter_v->x + (iter_v +1)->x + (iter_v +2)->x + (iter_v +3)->x;
                        R2 = iter_v->y + (iter_v +1)->y + (iter_v +2)->y + (iter_v +3)->y;

                        resultant = sqrt(pow(R1,2) + pow(R2,2));

                }   

        }
```

Consider this..............

Ok lets consider Points A[2,4], B[4,8], C[10,12], To add this vectors i add vectors/points I subtract point B x4 - A x2 and point B y8 - A y4 and point C x10 - B x4 and point C y12 - B y8 this will give me the the displacements between points....Now to get the Resultant i add all the Points X's and Y's  x's 2+4+10 = 16 y's 4+8+12 = 24, Next i would square root 16 ^2 + 24^2  = 28.84. So based on these calculations where resultant is a number not and x and y value how can i get the direction and angle....?

Comment: Off-topic. Basic math question. Look at the properties of dot products. Then summon arctangent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple summation of vectors.

```
(x, y) = (x1, y1) + (x2, y2) + ... = (x1+x2+..., y1+y2+...)
```

When you have the final vector, it's angle is found by using

```
tan(angle) = y/x
```

Comment: To add onto this, most programming languages will have a math library function atan2() that takes two variables, y and x. This allows it to return the right quadrant of the angle.

Comment: Ok lets consider Points A[2,4], B[4,8], C[10,12], To add this vectors i add vectors/points I subtract point B x4 - A x2 and point B y8 - A y4 and point C x10 - B x4 and point C y12 - B y8 this will give me the the displacements between points....Now to get the Resultant i add all the Points X's and Y's  x's 2+4+10 = 16 y's 4+8+12 = 24, Next i would square root 16 ^2 + 24^2  = 28.84. So based on these calculations where resultant is a number not and x and y value how can i get the direction and angle....? sorry for a long comment :P

Comment: Points are not vectors. (x,y) defines the vector by it's projection lengths on x and y. You need only two numbers to define a 2D vector. If you define it by using two points A (start) and B (end), then your vector is (xB-xA, yB-yA). And then you add them as I described.

Comment: In terms of your picture, you don't care about points B, C and D at all. Your vector is (xE-xA, yE-yA)

Comment: sqrt(x^2+y^2) is a vector length.

Comment: ok i see.....so in the case of the scenerio i have presented you with :P it would be  x = 10 - 2, y = 12-4, And based on these results to get the angle of that vector in Programming i would do this: float a = 8, float b = 8........... atan2(a,b)...? and this would give me the angle of that vector right now what about the direction..?

Comment: Direction is defined by angle. In your case, you go from A to E, so it is directed from A to E.

Comment: ooo ok :) in this case you have answers all my questions now its time go dive into Visual studio C++ and amend the solutions XD much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The angle between two vectors is generally defined as:

```
Angle = arccos( DotProduct(v1, v2) / ( Length(v1) * Length(v2) ) );
```

The direction is simply subtraction of the two vectors:

```
Direction = v2 - v1;
```

Usually, you have to normalize this to get a unit vector:

```
Len = SquareRoot( direction.x * direction.x + direction.y * direction.y );
Direction.x /= Len;
Direction.y /= Len;
```

Thus, you'll have a unit direction vector and the angle of the vector.